# MSBuild to update html tag

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <script id="ScriptId" src=""></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to replace empty src by script.js.

I tried with XmlPoke, but my XPath query doesn't work I think or maybe I can't do this way:

```
<XmlPoke XmlInputPath="test.html"
          Query="/html/body/script[id='ScriptId']/src"
          Value="script.js"/>
```

Thanks in advance to help me to update this src value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes in XPath are prefixed with `@`.

```
/html/body/script[@id='ScriptId']/@src
```

You probably shouldn't be using something designed for XML with HTML as two are not the same, at best, if HTML is well-formed, it'll strip out non-XML stuff like `DOCTYPE`, at worst it'll blow up.

Comment: Works even with DOCTYPE. Thank you.

Comment: @Alphapage it'll work *with* DOCTYPE, but it'll remove it from the output file.